# How to read from hdfs using spark-shell in Intel hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, intel

I am not able to read from HDFS (Intel distribution hadoop, Hadoop version is 1.0.3) from spark-shell(spark version is 1.2.1). I built spark using the command `mvn -Dhadoop.version=1.0.3 clean package`, started  spark-shell and read a HDFS file using `sc.textFile()` and the exception is:

> WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /10.xx.xx.xx:50010, add to
>   deadNodes and continuejava.net.SocketTimeoutException: 120000 millis
>   timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch :
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.xx.xx.xx:44264
>   remote=/10.xx.xx.xx:50010]
>   ...
>   ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
>   java.io.IOException: Could not obtain block:
>   blk_8724894648624652503_7309 file=/research/Files/README.md

Same question is asked here : http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201309.mbox/%3CF97ADEE4FBA8F6478453E148FE9E2E8D3CCA37A9@HASMSX106.ger.corp.intel.com%3E

This was the suggested solution:

**"In addition to specifying HADOOP_VERSION=1.0.3 in the ./project/SparkBuild.scala file, you will need to specify the libraryDependencies and name "spark-core"  resolvers. Otherwise, sbt will fetch version 1.0.3 of hadoop-core from apache instead of Intel. You can set up your own local or remote repository that you specify"**

Can anybody please elaborate on how to specify that SBT should fetch hadoop-core from Intel (which is available in our internal repository)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at [this page of the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-third-party-distributions.html)

Spark is using some SBT/maven integrations that I do not know a lot about, but it seem like the repositories are specified in [`pom.xml` in the root](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml)

If that does not work, you can explore the where the [sbt-files are specifying `resolvers`](https://github.com/apache/spark/search?l=scala&q=resolvers&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

---

For the record, this is an excerpt from the linked documentation

## Linking Applications to the Hadoop Version

In addition to compiling Spark itself against the right version, you need to add a Maven dependency on that version of hadoop-client to any Spark applications you run, so they can also talk to the HDFS version on the cluster. If you are using CDH, you also need to add the Cloudera Maven repository. This looks as follows in SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "<version>"

// If using CDH, also add Cloudera repo
resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
```

Or in Maven:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>[version]</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- If using CDH, also add Cloudera repo -->
  <repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>Cloudera repository</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried modifying the root POM.xml to include our internal repository, where we have hadoop-core jar for 1.0.3-Intel distribution of hadoop. But build fails with the following error:


`[ERROR] Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:1.0.3-Intel: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:1.0.3-Intel from/to internal (http://192.168.150.180:8081/archiva/repository/internal)`

We don't have the hadoop-client for hadoop-1.0.3-Intel version which seems to be unavailable in the web as well.
Any other solution.

Comment: Sorry. I do not have any experience with third party hadoop distributions, or what depends on `hadoop-client`.